# Sort array in java, by class field

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Could someone please help me out with the following problem in java. I have a simple class defined as below:

```
public class Expr {
  public long total_apparitions;
  public String expression=new String();

  public Expr(long total,String expr){
    this.total_apparitions=total;
    this.expression=expr;
  }

  public void increment(long aparitions){
    total_apparitions+=aparitions;
  }
}
```

I want to sort an array of `Expr` objects by the `total_apparitions` field, using the `Arrays.sort` built-in function. How do I specify to the `Arrays.sort` function the comparison factor? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Jason Braucht said, implement `Comparable` like this:

```
public class Expr implements Comparable {
  ...
  public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if(this.total_apparitions > ((Expr) o).total_apparitions)
      return 1;
    else if(this.total_apparitions < ((Expr) o).total_apparitions)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make `Expr` implement `java.lang.Comparable`

**Edit** - Should have provided an example (others already did).  Here's a full sample using generics.

```
public class Expr implements Comparable<Expr>
{

    public long total_apparitions;
    public String expression = new String();

    public Expr(long total, String expr)
    {
        this.total_apparitions = total;
        this.expression = expr;

    }

    public void increment(long aparitions)
    {
        total_apparitions += aparitions;
    }

    public int compareTo(Expr o)
    {
        if (total_apparitions > o.total_apparitions)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (total_apparitions < o.total_apparitions)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to implementing `Comparable`, you can pass a `Comparator` instance to the `Arrays.sort()` method. The advantage of doing it this way is that it allows you to have different concepts of sorting an array of objects of this type (say you might want to sort by the name later, in which case you just need a different implementation of the comparator).

For example:

```
public class ByApparationsComparator implements Comparator<Expr> {
  public int compare(Expr first, Expr second) {
    if (first.total_apparitions > second.total_apparitions) {
      return 1;
    } else if (first.total_apparitions < second.total_apparitions) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can say:

```
Arrays.sort(exprArray, new ByApparationsComparator());
```

Comment: but this makes his calling code look crowded. Implementing `Comparable` makes everything easier to read, and allows him to easily call the sort whenever he needs to.

Comment: It really depends if you might want to sort by something else at some later stage. If there's only one natural sort order, then implementing `Comparable` is the way to go.